# Position elements relative to parent of parent

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to place elements that are relative to parents of parents?

```
<div id='div1'>
   <div id='div2'>
       <input type='button' class='btn'> button 2</button>
       <input type='button' class='btn'>button 3</button>
       <input type='button' class='btn'>button 1</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

the css wanted is to arrange the buttons relative to the first div in the center vertically the css i tried

```
.btn{
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%)
  }
```

but this will center it relative to the second div. Which has a different size than that of the parent div is this possible?

Comment: What about giving us a JSFiddle showing what you have so the members here can play around with it

Comment: Also an image of what this is **supposed** to look like. Why can't you just center the `div2` element?

Comment: And maybe something to help visualise what you're trying to achieve?

If you're trying to position relative to div1, why are the elements contained in div2?

Comment: Also, please note that relative positioning never refers to a context other than "where would it be placed without repositioning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3531chbz/1/

The trick is you should  not give `position:` attribute to second div ie `#div2`, so in this case the child within second div will take position from its grand parent,

also position of input needs to be changed to `position:absolute`

**HTML**

```
<div id='div1'>
   <div id='div2'>
       <button class='btn'> button 2</button>
       <button class='btn'>button 3</button>
       <button class='btn'>button 1</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
    height:400px
}
#div2 {
    background-color:blue;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just center the `div2` which is wrapped around the buttons.

**Note**: This `<input type='button' class='btn'> button 2</button>` is not valid HTML

```css
#div1 {
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
}
#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
  <div id='div2'>
    <button class="btn">button 2</button>
    <button class="btn">button 3</button>
    <button class="btn">button 1</button>
  </div>
</div>
```